# Exception during creating then testing Azure Type connection in Airflow UI

Tags: airflow

I am facing an issue while creating a connection in Airflow UI,
Connection Type: Azure
I have the provider package installed.
Post selecting the connection type, I filled in all the fields and then clicked on test.
Post which I get the following error on the top of UI:

```
AzureBaseHook.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'azure_conn_id'
```

Additional Context:
I am trying to use a Service Principle that I created in Azure to use for connection in airflow.